# Facebook Graph API Comments grouped by filter

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get comments count for a post, but i want to get both filtered values.

```
post-id?ids=xxxxxxxxx&fields=comments.filter(stream).limit(0).summary(1)
```

and

```
post-id?ids=xxxxxxxxx&fields=comments.filter(toplevel).limit(0).summary(1)
```

is this possible with only one request ?

i already tried something like

```
post-id?ids=xxxxxxxxx&fields=comments.filter(toplevel,stream).limit(0).summary(1)
```

or

```
post-id?ids=xxxxxxxxx&fields=comments.filter(stream).limit(0).summary(1),comments.filter(toplevel).limit(0).summary(1)
```

thanks for any help :=)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it almost as you tried with the last line of code shown - but since you are requesting the same field (comments) twice, you must *alias* at least one of them (otherwise you’ll simply get an error saying that you requested the same field twice.)

```
?fields=comments.filter(stream).limit(0).summary(1).as(stream_comments),
        comments.filter(toplevel).limit(0).summary(1).as(toplevel_comments)
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields

Comment: Thx! I was looking for something like **AS**, don't know why i didn't find it.